# Unicode conversion

Tags: unicode, d, phobos, druntime

**Config:**

- OS: Windows 7 (32 bits)
- DMD 2.58 using Phobos standard library

---

**My Intent:**

I began to port a old package (10 modules) written back in 2007. It featured a full unicode support and I want to keep that capability.

Its author has written a specific module (`class UnicodeBom(T)`) for the purpose: A very involved approach (to my capacity at least, given that I am just an enthustiast and a beginner with only some C++/Qt/C# primer experience)!

I cleaned up any `Tango` code fragment from all the modules and succeeded to get to work on my box (at unit/module level for sure) only 4 modules out of 10 so far.

---

**Code fragment:**

```
this(Stream st) {
  void[] buf;
  buf.length = cast(uint) st.size;
  st.readBlock(buf.ptr, cast(uint) st.size);

  auto unicode = new UnicodeBom!(wchar)(Encoding.Unknown); // <<< to refactor
  mSourceBuffer = unicode.decode(buf); // <<< to refactor
}
```

where

- st (parameter) is a `std.stream.Stream`
- mSourceBuffer (private field) is a `wchar[]`

---

**Quote:**

Excerpt from code documentation related to `final T[] decode (void[] content)` method:

> Convert the provided content. The content is inspected
>   for a BOM signature, which is stripped. An exception is
>   thrown if a signature is present when, according to the
>   encoding type, it should not be. Conversely, An exception
>   is thrown if there is no known signature where the current
>   encoding expects one to be present

---

**My Question:**

Is there an up to date and more idiomatic approach using out of the box `Druntime` and/or `Phobos` resources leading to the same outcome (namely loading UTF8/16/32 files and converting them to wchar[] without BOM)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: I think they plan on deprecating Streams or something, in favor of ranges... just a heads up.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thank you for commenting. That's a valuable information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up succeeding to port all the modules to DMD 2.59 by fixing one by one all issues raised.